# C# Index and length must refer to a location within the string

Tags: c#, string, substring

i've got this error while i'm using the **substring** method.

i'm trying to execute this very simple code:

```
string bla = selected.Substring((selected.IndexOf('(')+1), (selected.Length-1))
```

selected value could be **blabla(bla)** and i want to get just the 'bla' inside the brackets...

edit: i want to know if there is a way to do everything on one line, thank for all the answers
edit2: the right answer is

```
selected.Substring((selected.IndexOf('(') + 1), (selected.Length - selected.IndexOf('(') - 2))
```

thank to sinatr, i did a stupid mistake

Comment: Second parameter is length, not last position.

Comment: What if `selected` is empty string?

Comment: thanks for reply but a)selected isn't empty and b)i know that the second parameter is lenght

Comment: Sometimes its better to use regex.

Comment: @Sinatr is right, but to clarify, the second parameter is the number of characters you want to select from the index of the character found. So you are trying to select more characters than there are left in the string. Hence the error.

Comment: If you know second parameter is length, then you are doing silly mistake. See for yourself with what parameters `Substring()` will be called. =D

Comment: thank you sinatr, srry, i was confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that simple. The second parameter of [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the length not the end-index.    You also have to to check if the index is >= 0 and use `String.IndexOf` with the overload that takes the start-index to find the correct end-index:

```
string selected = "blabla(bla)";
string bla = selected;
int index = selected.IndexOf('(');
if(index++ >= 0) // index++ because you want to omit (
{
    int endIndex = selected.IndexOf(')', index); // index is start-index to find )
    if (endIndex >= 0)
    {
        bla = selected.Substring(index, endIndex - index); // endIndex - index -> Length
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work given the simple scenario you presented:

```
string bla = selected.Split(new char[] { '(', ')' })[1];
```

Comment: One line answer, but with few assumptions: selected is not null, selected contains `'('` and `')'`, they occurs only once, you need text in-between (works for both: `"blabla(bla)"` or `"blabla)bla("`).

Comment: data is standard, i haven't specified it, srry. This is also a good solution

Answer (score 1):

You could also do that with regex, although it's kinda heavy artillery for that kind of a task ;)

```
string pattern = @"(?<=\()\w+(?=\))";
string input = "BLALBALBLA(BLA)";
string output;
Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
if(match.Success)
{
    output = match.Value;
}
```

Comment: oh my gosh, what the heck is regex?

Comment: Short for Regular Expression. It's a mechanism for advanced pattern searching. The pattern above tells the c# regex implemented `Match` method to find all words that are made of alpha-numeric characters succeeding `(` sign and preceding `)` sign. If you're gonna program in the future, you'll have to learn it sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

according to Substring, thesecondparameter is Length of the substring, then you may code
ASSUMING the string is well formatted, not empty..

```
int l_a = selected.IndexOf('(') + 1;
int l_b = selected.IndexOf(')');
string bla = selected.Substring(l_a,l_b-l_a)
```

Comment: Please don't use l_ prefix for local variables. That results in totally unreadable code.

Answer (score 0):

Here your problem solved with regex. Will match anything behind first `(` except the last char.

```
string bla = "blabla(bla)";

Match match = Regex.Match(bla, @"\((.*).");
if (match.Success)
{
    bla = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

and if you are sure it matches you can do it as oneliner:

```
bla = Regex.Match(bla, @"\((.*).").Groups[1].Value;
```